# How do I make permanent changes to a variable within for loops so that the variable doesn't reset every iteration?

Tags: c#

I want to replace characters in a string iteratively using the **`string.Replace()`** function in a for loop however every iteration the string itself resets and no changes made in the previous loop stay. Ending up in the string undergoing no changes overall.

I've tried making the string a class member but that didn't work,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i;
    string strOne = "abcdefg";

    for (i=0; i < (strOne.Length - 1); i++)
    {
        string c = Convert.ToString(strOne[i]);
        strOne.Replace(c, "1");   
    }
}
```

I expect the output of **1111111** but instead i get **abcdefg**.

Comment: `strOne.Replace` returns a new, modified string. It doesn't change `strOne`. You probably wanted to do `strOne = strOne.Replace(c, "1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `string.Replace()`, it does not modify the string itself. Instead, it returns the string with the replaced characters. Therefore, you need to do this: `strOne = strOne.Replace(c, "1");`